# Recommend - a Unified Email Inbox, Should be accessible on web (web based) & Android

Tags: android, web-apps, html, email, email-client

I want a software to do the following:

1. Can linked my emails to one account, so that I need to open only one account to access my emails.
2. Can show me unified inbox, so that I can access all my inbox emails from all my linked emails at once.
3. send or reply from the same email account every time or provide option to select which email to use for sending email.
4. Let me create quick responses and use them when replying to an email.
5. Let me use HTML email Template.

Thank you,

Please recommend me on the basis of my requirement. feel free to ask me questions.

Comment: IMHO that can be done with *GMail* and either the *GMail* app or [Inbox by GMail](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox). But I've never tried that (I don't like to trust a 3rd party with so much personal information), so I cannot say for sure whether all your requirements are met there.

Comment: Roundcube (webmail) and K9 (Android) with every service offering IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly agree with @Izzy's comment and have used [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/) for this sort of thing for years. I use it for half a dozen addresses each at my private domain and two business domains.

- Can linked my emails to one account, so that I need to open only one
  account to access my emails.     ✔
- Can show me unified inbox, so that I can access all my inbox emails
  from all my linked emails at once.  ✔
- send or reply from the same email account every time or provide
  option to select which email to use for sending email.    ✔
- Let me create quick responses and use them when replying to an email.   ✔ `(using Gmail labs)`
- Let me use HTML email Template.  ✔ `see http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_templates.htm and Google for others`

Plus many other fine features, more storage space than I will ever need and great search capabilities (and integration with other Google products, which I don't use, so can't comment on. Google drive, Google odcs, et al).

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Mail.com](http://www.mail.com/). It is able to,

- Link multiple email accounts to one "unified" email account.
- Can send/reply and receive emails from all the linked email accounts.
- Can use HTML email templates to send emails.
- Has a web based email client and has an Android mobile app.
- Free and premium options

As for the fourth requirement, I am not sure if this is possible. I will look into this and update this if this is possible though mail.com. You can however use auto-responders if that works.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments nearly every advanced mail-(imap-)client will fit your needs!

---

if you want to use a cloud-service for this i can recommend [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) (a full cloud-software for files, contacts, calendars and [much more](https://apps.owncloud.com/) via self-hosting at home, hosting on your own web-space or by [external providers](https://owncloud.org/providers/)) with their [Mail app](https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/Mail?content=169914) installed.

[image: ownCloud Mail app]
the Mail app is an IMAP-client written in PHP under heavy [development](https://github.com/owncloud/mail) with following features:

- you can use multiple mail accounts
- unified inbox
- mobile support
- send & receive encrypted emails using the [Mailvelope browser extension](https://mailvelope.com)